# Parameter of OfType<????> when used in a method with C#

Tags: c#, linq, oftype

I have this code to get "A" as a filtered result.

```
public static void RunSnippet()
{
    Base xbase = new Base(); 
    A a = new A(); 
    B b = new B();
    IEnumerable<Base> list = new List<Base>() { xbase, a, b };
    Base f = list.OfType<A>().FirstOrDefault();
    Console.WriteLine(f);
}
```

I need to use `IEnumerable<Base> list = new List<Base>() {xbase, a, b};` from a function as follows:

```
public static Base Method(IEnumerable<Base> list, Base b (????)) // I'm not sure I need Base b parameter for this?
{
    Base f = list.OfType<????>().FirstOrDefault();
    return f;
}

public static void RunSnippet()
{
    Base xbase = new Base(); 
    A a = new A(); 
    B b = new B();
    IEnumerable<Base> list = new List<Base>() { xbase, a, b };
    //Base f = list.OfType<A>().FirstOrDefault();
    Base f = Method(list);
    Console.WriteLine(f);
}
```

What parameter do I use in '????' to get the same result from the original code?

Comment: You can't call `Method(list)` - `list` isn't a `Base`, it's an `IEnumerable<Base>`. That's the second time you've made that error - how comfortable are you with `IEnumerable<T>`? And is `Method` *always* meant to return an `A` value? If so, why is it declared to return `Base`, and why can't you just use `A` instead of `????` ?

Comment: @Jon: The parameter of Method() should have been `IEnumerable<Base> list, Base b`. For ????, I need to get the type A from the second parameter. I tried with (Base b) as the parameter, and b.GetType() in <????>, but it doesn't work as b.GetType() return Type not Base.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like you are looking for a generic way to do what is in `Method` based on different children types of `Base`. You can do that with:

```
public static Base Method<T>(IEnumerable<Base> b) where T: Base
{
    Base f = list.OfType<T>().FirstOrDefault();
    return f;
}
```

This will return the first instance from `b` that is of type `T` (which has to be a child of `Base`).

Comment: Note that although this was accepted, it doesn't conform to what the question actually asked for - namely getting the type from a parameter value. It's a somewhat confused question, admittedly...

Comment: My original answer was far less _sure_ of what they were asking, and apparently correctly so. It was my attempt at trying to do something useful. Hopefully it actually helped. :)

Answer (score 2):

**If** you want to query on a type, you can try something like this:

```
public static Base Method(IEnumerable<Base> list, Type typeToFind)
{
   Base f =  (from l in list  
       where l.GetType()== typeToFind 
               select l).FirstOrDefault();
   return f;
}
```

If it's not what you are searching for, please clarify.

Comment: @M.Babcock: Do you mean OfType, or typeof?

Comment: @JonSkeet - Edited (or rather reposted because I didn't catch it in time).

Comment: @M.Babcock: Okay - in which case I can answer by saying that no, they're actually different for subtypes; and for OfType you have to know T at compile-time. You can't use `OfType<typeToFind>`.

Comment: @JonSkeet - Thanks for the clarification. I don't know that I've ever used it myself in practice. That actually makes it less useful than I had assumed it was.

Comment: If list contains null, will throw exception by GetType.